# Fetch keys from multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, html-table

I have a multidimensional array returned from PHP `fetchAll()` function like this:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10";
 $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute();
 $numcolumn = $stmt->columnCount();  
 $res = $stmt -> fetchAll();
```

**IT RETURNS an array like this.**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (   [0] => 1
            [id] => 1
            [1] => Firstname one
            [firstname] => Firstname one
            [2] => Lastname one
            [lastname] => Lastname one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [id] => 1
            [1] => Firstname one
            [firstname] => Firstname one
            [2] => Lastname one
            [lastname] => Lastname one
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [id] => 1
            [1] => Firstname one
            [firstname] => Firstname one
            [2] => Lastname one
            [lastname] => Lastname one
        )
)
```

**How  can I print this data in a html table like this in PHP with loop?**

```
<table>
<th>
 <td>id</td>
 <td>firstname</td>
 <td>lastname</td>
</th>
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>Firstname one</td>
 <td>Lastname one</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Note that the keys and values both are from the database, not static. Please help.
**EDITED :**
***IT is for keys (not working) :***

```
$keys = array_keys($res);
    for($i = 0; $i < 1 ; $i++) {
       foreach($res[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {

        $msg.="<th style='background-color:red;'>";
        $msg.= $key;  //will store column name of the table to msg variable
        $msg.="</th>";

      }}
     $msg.="</tr>";
     $i=0;
      $count=1; //used to print sl.no
```

**it is for values(working)  :**

```
foreach($res as $row){
  $msg.="<tr><td>".$count."</td>";
    for($i=0;$i< $numcolumn;$i++)
    {
        $var=$row[$i]; //will store all the values of row 
        $msg.="<td style='white-space: nowrap;word-break: keep-all;'>".$var."</td>";
    }
    $count=$count+1;
    $msg.="</tr>";
}

$msg.="</table>";
echo $msg;
```

**ANSWER :**

```
     $res = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     $msg="<table><tr><th style='white-space: nowrap;background-color:red;'>Serial No.</th>";
// for keys:
    $keys = array_keys($res);
        for($i = 0; $i < 1 ; $i++) 
        {
           foreach($res[$keys[$i]] as $keyg => $value) 
           {
              $msg.="<th style='background-color:red;'>";
              $msg.= $keyg;  //will store column name of the table to msg variable
              $msg.="</th>";          
           }
        }
            $msg.="</tr>";
            $i=0;
            $count=1; //used to print sl.no
  //for values  
     foreach($res as $row => $key)
    {
       $msg.="<tr><td>".$count."</td>";

        foreach($key as $C=>$d)
        {
            $var = $d;
            $msg.="<td style='white-space: nowrap;word-break: keep-all;'>".$var."</td>";
        }

       $count=$count+1;
       $msg.="</tr>";
    }

    $msg.="</table>";
    echo $msg;  //for printing table in html
```

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Before posting, do some research. There are _many_ tutorials/guides/examples about this if you just spend a few minutes searching.

Comment: i have tried every tutorials,so posted a question here . i am stuck in printing keys from a multidimensional array.

Comment: Add your attempt.

Comment: edited the question .please read question carefully..

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `while` loop something like this

```
 while($res)
 {
 echo "<tr><td>" . $res['id'] . "</td>" .
     "<td>" . $res['firstname'] . "</td>" .
     "<td>"  . $res['lastname'] . "</td></tr>";
 }
```

Comment: i am saying that i have to print both keys and value dynamically by loop.not staticaly ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `foreach` loop.

Before iterating the results using loop you can add the field names in table head.

```
foreach ($res as $row) {
    echo "<tr>" .
             "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>" .
             "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>" .
             "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>" .
         "</tr>";
}
```

**Edit**: Use indexes for dynamic fields.

You can try something like this.

```
foreach ($res as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i=0; $i<$numcolumn; $i++) {
        echo "<td>" . $row[$i] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: i am saying that i have to print both keys and value dynamically by loop.not staticaly ?

Comment: @AnkitMishra You need to try with indexes, please check updated answer.

Comment: it is for values,can u tell me how to print keys of arrays with loop,i mean table columns from database